# How to get the value of a promise from async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I am struggling to understand how to get the value of a promise within Javascript

```
  const data = personId && personId.map(async x => x.value)

  console.log(data);
```

it returns me: [image]

I would like to get the value of s121570.

Thanks!

Comment: The only way from your Javascript to get a value out of a promise is with `.then()` or with `await`.  And, if you have an array of promises, you would use `Promise.all()` to know when all the promises in the array are done and then use `.then()` or `await` on the promise returned from `Promise.all()` to get your array of values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using async/await and returning an array of promises via `map`, you need to `Promise.all` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all))

```
const data = personId && await Promise.all(personId.map(async x => x.value));
console.log(data); // Array of data/resolved promises
```